# Gatsby's StaticImage not rendering in Storybook

Tags: javascript, gatsby, storybook

I'm trying to write a storybook for my component with Gatsby's `StaticImage` but this ends up in nothing at all rendered and an error disguised as warning in the console:

```
Please ensure that "gatsby-plugin-image" is included in the plugins array in gatsby-config.js, and that your version of gatsby is at least 2.24.78
(anonymous) @ static-image.server.tsx:52
```

I wonder if there's a way to render component using `StaticImage` outside of Gatsby?

Component is trivial:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StaticImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image';

export const Card = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{title}</div>
      <StaticImage src="../../assets/images/background.png" alt="" width={300} height={100}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'm using Gatsby v3 & Storybook v6.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Gatsby Documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/testing/visual-testing-with-storybook/#writing-stories), it isn't presently supported yet.

> Note: Writing stories for components that use StaticImage from gatsby-plugin-image is currently not supported. Contributions to making this possible are welcome.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that! Apparently it's time to migrate to next.js...